# Template Argument Deduction for Pointer to Member Function

Tags: c++, templates, c++-cx

I know there are a lot of other similar questions, but none of the ones I have looked at seem to apply to what I'm doing. The jist of what I have is:

```
template <typename T>
void CallFn(T *p, void (T::*pfn)(void))
{
    (p->*pfn)();
}
```

called using:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    void Bar(void);
}
...
Foo *p = ...
CallFn(p, &Foo::Bar);
```

but that gives me an error saying the complier couldn't deduce template arguments for the pointer to member function. If I instead use a struct like so:

```
template <typename T>
class Wrapper
{
public:
    void operator()(T *p, void (T::*pfn)(void))
    {
        (p->*pfn)();
    }
};
...
Foo *p = ...
Wrapper<Foo> x;
x(p, &Foo::Bar);
```

it works, but the syntax is much more horrible. I was just wondering why the compiler could deduce the type of the member function for the class, but not for the function.

Comment: The first one looks like a potential candidate for _SFINAE_... Could you show us how do you invoke those two? There could be something different in the way you do that

Comment: Updated! Thanks for the feedback, I'll look into it a little bit more

Comment: What you show works just fine in several compilers (e.g., http://ideone.com/fNh9X1) Is that your real code? What compiler are you using?

Comment: One more question, in your actual code, does it work if you do `CallFn<Foo>(p, &Foo::Bar);`?

Comment: Interesting. I'm using the VC++ compiler (v110). And yes, calling it like CallFn<Foo>(...) does work, thanks! A little disappointing that I have to do that, but it'll work.

Comment: Duncan: You don't have to do that, your sample code works fine with VC++ (v110) as well. You are triggering _SFINAE_ in your real usage, that is what is going on, but I can't tell you any more if you don't show us actual code that causes the problem

Comment: K-ballo: Hmm, okay thanks. The code I have right now is far too bloated to post here. I reduced it down to essentially what I posted; the only difference is it's using a WinRT type (so Foo ^ instead of Foo *), and that still didn't work. I'll look into it a little bit more.

Comment: The specific error is `error C2784: 'void CallFn(T ^,void (__thiscall T::* )(void))' : could not deduce template argument for 'void (__thiscall T::* )(void)' from 'void (__cdecl Foo::* )(void)'`

Comment: Update: I can get it to work with non-WinRT types. I'll report the bug later assuming this is the incorrect functionality. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @Duncan: So not only you posted a use case that didn't exhibited the problem, but you also specified the wrong language? I don't think that's a bug anyway, not on whichever of the many C++ deviant variants MSVC has...

Comment: C++/CX shouldn't deviate that much. As far as I know template type deduction should work the same as with vanilla C++. Anyway, I'll look more into whether or not this is a bug

Comment: The problem is that the parameter and the argument have differen't calling conventions: The parameter has `__thiscall` (which is correct for member functions) while the argument has `__cdecl`, which is normally used for free / static functions. Do you explicitly mark the memberfunction as `__cdecl`?

Comment: @Xeo No. I can even explicitly declare the function pointer with `__cdecl` and it will still fail, but will have `__cdecl` as the calling convention for both function pointers.

Comment: Also, this appears to be an old issue with no resolution: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/85e605b0-6390-42e0-a149-a0730bcf9f6b/template-deduction-with-a-ref-class-involved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, there appears to be a couple of things going on here. First, the calling convention is wrong, and there should be a `__cdecl` in the PMF. Secondly, after doing so, the issue still persists. This is a confirmed bug in the Visual Studio VC++ compiler